# Gitblit push error "error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0"

Tags: git, push, rpc, gitblit

Setup gitlbit on my Mac OS X 10.8, but keeps failing to push!

In the Gitblit web interface, I created an empty repository called empty and cloned it to local storage by the following command:

```
git clone https://localhost:8443/git/test/empty.git
```

I added a file and commit the change and added a remote

```
git remote add gitblit https://localhost:8443/git/test/empty.git
```

then I try to push with:

```
git push -v gitblit master
```

and the error shows:

```
Pushing to https://localhost:8443/git/test/empty.git
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 215 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
POST git-receive-pack (351 bytes)
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried the ssl and the buffer settings, but no help.

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
git config http.sslVerify false 
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
config --global --bool --add http.sslVerify false
```

My Gitblit settings of bindings are all set to blank to accept binding to all interfaces:

```
server.httpBindInterface = 
server.httpsBindInterface = 
server.ajpBindInterface =
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed my problem with update the git version to the newest(2.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late, but I just ran into this problem myself, and future users may find this helpful.

My group at work was setting up our own git server, but forgot to add write permissions to the remote repository for group.

Adding group write permissions with chmod did the trick.

Comment: Interesting.  There is an open issue to support the equivalent of git init --bare --shared which may pre-emptively address this problem.